# Put ViewBag Controller Value on View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I'm trying to pass a `ViewBag` data from my controller to my View, if i put the `Viewbag` on a `Html.DropDownList` I get the correct values but if I use   `<input value="@ViewBag.Group" />` I only get `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectList"`
Why am I not getting the value of my `viewbag`?

This is my controller ViewBag:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string Selected)
    {
       List<string> listadesumas = new List<string>();
        var db = new PosContext();

      foreach (var item in db.Pos)
        {
            listadesumas.Add(item.ToString());

        }
        var grupos = new SelectList(listadesumas.ToList());

        ViewBag.Group = grupos;
 return View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml",db.Pos.ToList());
    }
```

and my Input From View:

```
  <input value="@ViewBag.Group" />
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: [Why are you using viewbag instead of strongly typing your view by passing a model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)?  After all the M in MVC stands for Model..  :)

Comment: When you call `@ViewBag.Group` you get values of your `grupos` variable stringified using `.ToString()` by .Net itself. Consider using viewmodel with strongly typed properties so that you could estimate what objects with what types you work with, and what operations you can do.

Comment: i already have a model passed to my view, i cant merge it or add more variables to it thats why im passing a viewbag

Comment: A `SelectList` is a a class associated with creating a dropdownlist (a `<select>` tag) but your claiming your do not want a dropdownlist, therefore don't use it. What do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
   var group = (SelectList)ViewBag.Group
 }
```

`<select>
    @foreach(var item in group)
    {
      <option value='@item'>@item</option>

    }
</select>`

Comment: i need input or labels not dropdown list im not having trouble with dropdown list so i updated your code but im stil not getting results 
@foreach (var item in group)
                                            {
                                              
                                                <input value="@item" />
                                            }

Comment: <input value="@item" /> it should get a string, im passing a selectedlist but it only have one data

Comment: Why are you passing `SelecteList` when you just wanted to render as text?Pass the array to `ViewBag` and in the view you can just `foreach`

Comment: its pretty confusing but sometimes i may get a list of items witch then i need to display them all thats why i used selectedlist the problem was that even in a foreach in my view i didnt got the values of the list only references but i used a boxlist and that make it work

Answer (score 0):

Viewbag.Group contains a list of values. An input tag can only take exactly one value.

Comment: the witch tag should be better? i need it like a label or stamp no matter if i had to make a foreach but i dont want a dropdown

Comment: What are you looking for if you don't want a drop down?

Answer (score 0):

i manage to get another aproach using a boxlist, heres the code in case someone needs it:

```
   @Html.ListBox("Group", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Group)
```

Comment: Even this will render as `select` tag